# Can an external keyboard be hooked up to the lenovo ultrabook ideapad U310?

Tags: lenovo-laptop

Can an external keyboard be hooked up to this laptop? The screen is cracked and I am now looking to connect the computer to a monitor and external keyboard for usage.

Answer (score 1):

Use a USB keyboard.  Unless the existing keyboard has stuck keys or other issues you should be good.

Comment: Can someone explain a downvote?   Not sure why this is wrong

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is no damage to onboard keyboard (stuck keys, etc), as USB keyboard should work fine.